# How can I browse a local html site?

Tags: html, firefox

I'm running into two issues trying to browse a local html site on firefox for testing:

1. When I try to make a link to the root (href="/"), firefox shows the macos root directory on a file browser
2. When I go to a directory, firefox shows a file browser rather than opening index.html
   This seems to be fixed by uploading the site to the internet, but I'd like to be able to test the site locally without uploading it

Comment: Install and setup a local web server.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) may help.

Comment: thanks! "python3 -m http.server 8000" worked great